# Making an Overlapping Sequin Shader with Fixed Scale

Tags: materials

This may be quite an odd question, but I hope I can phrase it right.

Some friends of mine have been wondering if there is a possible way to make a Sequin shader that can support overlaps and randomness.

Their method for getting circle sequins is with a Voronoi Texture and a Color Ramp. However, this method introduces this "overlap" where the sequins are "blended" with each other.

[image: 1]

We've tried lowering Randomness to avoid this issue, but to that point it started looking too uniform. Additionally, Randomness results in random Scale, and we've yet to find a way to resolve that.

An alternative setup I made, with the help from other questions on this site, is a tiled Randomness 0 Voronoi Texture with some options.
[image: 2]

The idea was to use multiple of these shaders and stack them on top of each other with math, but unfortunately, it still looks slightly too uniform for taste (and was also surprisingly laggy on our devices)
[image: 3]

Here is the node setup if you're curious, but I doubt it'd be much help.
[image: 4]

Anyway, that's about the situation we're facing, and I'm exhausted from researching and experimenting, so I thought it's about time I'd ask here for help. Appreciate any help!

## ALSO

It's perfectly fine if there is a completely different setup to this than a Voronoi. The end goal is just a random distribution of circles with a fixed size that can overlap with each other.  Or at least a random distribution of circles that don't overlap and can be stacked on top of each other.

It's also okay if we have to compromise with some uniformity if you guys think it's the best way.

And here's a reference I found, just in case if I didn't phrase it well enough on what we're looking for.

[image: 5]

Again, I appreciate any help given!